# Is it possible to change the scroll bar color in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, scrollbar

Often when I'm browsing a web page with a lot of content, the scroll bar is hard to find because the contrast between the position of the clickable part and the background is low.

It would be great if there was a way for me to change the color of the clickable part of the scroll bar so that I could see it better. Is this possible?

Comment: Looked around for a good 10 minutes and didn't find anything helpful =p

Comment: Try Decor8 (http://stardock.com/products/decor8/index.asp). If it doesn't support it, request the feature and hope the developers will add it.

Comment: @magicandre1981    
It seems to me like the feature set for Decor8 is focused on the Win8 start screen, whereas I'm looking at desktop apps (specifically Chrome) and their color scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scrollbar color is defined by the Windows theme.

For browsers you can use a custom CSS. In your case, for Google Chrome you can install extension 'Stylish' and add a new style with the following code:

```css
body {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 12px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
```

Optionally the style can be further improved with:

```css
html { overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question and after tinkering with the CSS a little bit, I think I can tweak it to my liking. Good answer.

Comment: I have the same problem - but also with other programs than just the browser. I'd love to see a solution that covers the scrollbar for all windows.